# Can't find any functions in ranges::view namespace

Tags: c++, range-v3, vcpkg

2 weeks ago I asked some questions and I haven't found a solution yet.
I'm using visual studio 2019 and I installed range-v3 library via vcpkg.
I know vcpkg version is not latest, but is it really different from latest version?
I only found some functions with _fn.

```
std::vector<int> const vi{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
using namespace ranges;
auto rng = vi | views::remove_if([](int i) { return i % 2 == 1; }) // ican't find remove_if function
| views::transform([](int i) { return std::to_string(i); });
// rng == {"2","4","6","8","10"};
return 0;
```

[image: screenshots]

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot you are looking for name completions from the `ranges::view::` namespace. This namespace has been deprecated in favor of `ranges::views::` which is what you should be using.